# ILE RPG - How to convert a time value to a numeric value?

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

Consider the following code:

```
D#TIME1           S               T                                             
D#numeric1        S              6  0                                           
D#numeric2        S              6  0                                           
D                                                                               
C                   TIME                    #numeric1                           
C                   eval      #TIME1 = %TIME(#numeric1:*HMS)                    
C                                                                               
C*                  This does not work:                                             
C                   eval      #numeric2 = %int(TIME1)                           
C*                  Errormessage: The expression contains a operator, which is not defined
C                                                                               
C                   MOVE      *ON           *INLR
```

Can someone please tell me, how I can convert a *HMS time value(like '07:02:22') to a `6 0` numeric value. I need this for comparing two time stamps.

Comment: Note that you can compare time or timestamp values directly without the need to convert them.

Comment: How to? Just `time_stmp1 IFGE time_stmp2`?

Comment: To compare two timestamps: IF time_stmp1 >= time_stmp2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
C                   eval      #numeric2 = %dec(TIME1: *hms)
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: perfect! Thanks :D

Comment: http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/05/rpgle-convert-date-to-numeric-or.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Time field in the result field of the TIME opcode. Or, to get the current time, you can use %TIME() with no parameters.

```
D#TIME1           S               T
D#curTime         S               T

C                   TIME                    #curTime 
C                   IF        #TIME1 >= #curTime
```

Or if you don't need the current time later, just use %TIME() directly in the comparison:

```
C                   IF        #TIME1 >= %time()
```